# Копирование С

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

int getline2(char line[], int maxline);
void copy(char to[], char from[]);

/* Вывод самой длинной строки в потоке */
int main()
{
    int len;                /* Длина текущей строки */
    int max;                /* Текущая максимальная длина */
    char line[MAXLINE];     /* Текущая введенная строка */
    char longest[MAXLINE];  /* Cамая длинная строка из введенных */

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline2(line, MAXLINE)) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy(longest, line);
        }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;
}

/* Считывает строку в s, возращает ее длину */
int getline2(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    for (i = 0; i < lim - 1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        s[i] = c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

/* Копирует строку from в to; длина to считается достаточной */
void copy(char to[], char from[])
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while ((to[i] = from[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Данная программа из Кернигана и Ричи сильно устарела в силу того, что в одном из изданий уже была добавлена функция getline, а как мы знаем, мы не вправе использовать зарезервированные имена. Но все равно очень хотелось бы разобраться в программке, которая считывает набор строк и выводит самую длинную из них.

Алгоритм программы довольно прост

```
while(поступает следующая строка)
if (она длиннее предыдущей самой длинной)
   сохранить ее 
   сохранить ее длину.
Вывести самую длинную строку.
```

Вы не могли бы, пожалуйста, чуточку подробней рассказать, как здесь работает функция копирования и почему в getline2 мы ставим условие `i<lim-1`, а не `i<lim`. Потому что в памяти при размещении массива символов нам понадобится одно место под `\0`?

Comment: @proxyarr, в функции copy (насколько я понимаю) авторы демонстрируют, что операция присваивания *вырабатывает значение*, которое можно использовать (например в операции сравнения).

Видимо далее в тексте будет сказано, что значением операции сравнения является либо ложь (**в Си это 0**) либо истина (**не ноль**).

Тогда цикл `while` можно переписать покороче

    while (to[i] = from[i++]); // да, так вот, без тела !!!

а далее Вы можете увидеть и так

    void copy (char to[], char from[]) {
        while (*to++ = *from++);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, `i<lim-1` поскольку индекс массива начинается с 0, и место под завершающий ноль `'\0'` необходимо оставить

Answer (score 0):

Есть также функция strlen которая возвращает количество символов без учета '\0'.